# How to optimally update state from parent in double nested child componenet (with hooks)?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

[Link to video with issue outlined below!](https://i.imgur.com/hQlrbv5.mp4)

Hello, currently my issue is that, when I click the DeleteButton (found in the SortableItem component), while the mutation successfully works, it requires a refresh to show the deletion.  What would be the most optimal way to refresh this as soon as the DeleteButton mutation is run?  I believe it requires my updating the state from RankList component within the SortableItem component but would like to know the optimal way to achieve this!

**RankList.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { Form } from "semantic-ui-react";
import moment from "moment";

import DeleteButton from "../components/DeleteButton";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import { SortableContainer, SortableElement } from "react-sortable-hoc";
import arrayMove from "array-move";
import "../RankList.css";
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from "react-transition-group";

// function SortableItem({ value, listId, listItemId }) {
//   return SortableElement(() => (
//     <>
//       <li className="listLI">{value}</li>
//       <DeleteButton listId={listId} listItemId={listItemId} />
//     </>
//   ));
// }

const SortableItem = SortableElement(
  ({ deleteItem, value, listId, listItemId }) => (
    <>
      <li className="listLI">{value}</li>
      <DeleteButton
        listId={listId}
        listItemId={listItemId}
        deleteItem={deleteItem}
      />
    </>
  )
);

const SortableList = SortableContainer(({ deleteItem, items, listId }) => {
  return (
    <ol className="theList">
      {/* <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="ranklist"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
      > */}
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <SortableItem
          deleteItem={deleteItem}
          listId={listId}
          listItemId={item.id}
          key={`item-${item.id}`}
          index={index}
          value={item.body}
        />
      ))}
      {/* </CSSTransitionGroup> */}
    </ol>
  );
});

function RankList(props) {
  const listId = props.match.params.listId;
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const listItemInputRef = useRef(null);

  const [state, setState] = useState({ items: [] });
  const [listItem, setListItem] = useState("");

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FETCH_LIST_QUERY, {
    variables: {
      listId,
    },
    // onError(err) {
    //   console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    //   // setErrors(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    // }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.getList && data.getList.listItems) {
      setState(() => ({ items: data.getList.listItems }));
    }
  }, [data]);

  // const [state, setState] = useState({ items: data.getList.listItems });

  const deleteItem = (listItem) => {
    let temp = state.items.filter((item) => item.id !== listItem);
    console.log(temp);
    setState(() => ({ items: temp }));
  };

  const [submitListItem] = useMutation(SUBMIT_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION, {
    update() {
      setListItem("");
      listItemInputRef.current.blur();
    },
    variables: {
      listId,
      body: listItem,
    },
  });

  const [editListItems] = useMutation(EDIT_LIST_ITEMS_MUTATION, {
    variables: {
      listId,
      listItems: state.items,
    },
  });

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error..</p>;

  function deleteListCallback() {
    props.history.push("/");
  }

  function onSortEnd({ oldIndex, newIndex }) {
    setState(({ items }) => ({
      items: arrayMove(items, oldIndex, newIndex),
    }));

    state.items.map((list) => delete list["__typename"]);

    editListItems();
  }

  let listMarkup;
  if (!data.getList) {
    listMarkup = <p>Loading list...</p>;
  } else {
    const {
      id,
      title,
      createdAt,
      username,
      listItems,
      comments,
      likes,
      likeCount,
      commentCount,
    } = data.getList;

    console.log(id);

    listMarkup = user ? (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="rankListMain">
          <div className="rankItemInput">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <Form>
              <div className="ui action input fluid">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Choose rank item.."
                  name="listItem"
                  value={listItem}
                  onChange={(event) => setListItem(event.target.value)}
                  ref={listItemInputRef}
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="ui button teal"
                  disabled={listItem.trim() === ""}
                  onClick={submitListItem}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </Form>
          </div>
          <SortableList
            deleteItem={deleteItem}
            items={state.items}
            listId={id}
            onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
            helperClass="helperLI"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div className="todoListMain">
        <div className="rankListMain">
          <div className="rankItemInput">
            <h3>{props.title}</h3>
          </div>
          {/* <SortableList
            items={listItems}
            // onSortEnd={onSortEnd}
            helperClass="helperLI"
          /> */}
          <ol className="theList">
            {/* <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="ranklist"
        transitionEnterTimeout={500}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={300}
      > */}
            {listItems.map((item, index) => (
              <li
                className="listLI"
                key={`item-${item.id}`}
                index={index}
                value={item.body}
              >
                {item.body}
              </li>
            ))}
            {/* </CSSTransitionGroup> */}
          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return listMarkup;
}

const EDIT_LIST_ITEMS_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($listId: ID!, $listItems: [ListItems]!) {
    editListItems(listId: $listId, listItems: $listItems) {
      id
      listItems {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
    }
  }
`;

const SUBMIT_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation($listId: ID!, $body: String!) {
    createListItem(listId: $listId, body: $body) {
      id
      listItems {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
      comments {
        id
        body
        createdAt
        username
      }
      commentCount
    }
  }
`;

const FETCH_LIST_QUERY = gql`
  query($listId: ID!) {
    getList(listId: $listId) {
      id
      title
      createdAt
      username
      listItems {
        id
        createdAt
        username
        body
      }
      likeCount
      likes {
        username
      }
      commentCount
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
        body
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default RankList;
```

**DeleteButton.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

import { Button, Confirm, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

import { FETCH_LISTS_QUERY, FETCH_LIST_QUERY } from "../util/graphql";
import MyPopup from "../util/MyPopup";

function DeleteButton({ listId, listItemId, commentId, deleteItem, callback }) {
  const [confirmOpen, setConfirmOpen] = useState(false);

  let mutation;

  if (listItemId) {
    mutation = DELETE_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION;
  } else if (commentId) {
    mutation = DELETE_COMMENT_MUTATION;
  } else {
    mutation = DELETE_LIST_MUTATION;
  }

  // const mutation = commentId ? DELETE_COMMENT_MUTATION : DELETE_LIST_MUTATION;

  const [deleteListOrComment] = useMutation(mutation, {
    update(proxy) {
      setConfirmOpen(false);
      // remove list from cache
      if (!commentId && !listItemId) {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
          query: FETCH_LISTS_QUERY,
        });
        const resLists = data.getLists.filter((p) => p.id !== listId);
        proxy.writeQuery({
          query: FETCH_LISTS_QUERY,
          data: { getLists: [...resLists] },
        });
      }

      if (callback) callback();
    },
    variables: {
      listId,
      listItemId,
      commentId,
    },
    onError(err) {
      console.log(err.graphQLErrors[0].extensions.exception.errors);
    },
  });

  return (
    <>
      <MyPopup content={commentId ? "Delete comment" : "Delete list"}>
        <Button
          as="div"
          color="red"
          floated="right"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setConfirmOpen(true);
          }}
        >
          <Icon name="trash" style={{ margin: 0 }} />
        </Button>
      </MyPopup>
      <Confirm
        open={confirmOpen}
        onCancel={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setConfirmOpen(false);
        }}
        onConfirm={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          deleteListOrComment();
          deleteItem(listItemId);
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const DELETE_LIST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation deleteList($listId: ID!) {
    deleteList(listId: $listId)
  }
`;

const DELETE_LIST_ITEM_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation deleteListItem($listId: ID!, $listItemId: ID!) {
    deleteListItem(listId: $listId, listItemId: $listItemId) {
      id
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
        body
      }
      commentCount
    }
  }
`;

const DELETE_COMMENT_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation deleteComment($listId: ID!, $commentId: ID!) {
    deleteComment(listId: $listId, commentId: $commentId) {
      id
      comments {
        id
        username
        createdAt
        body
      }
      commentCount
    }
  }
`;
export default DeleteButton;
```

Comment: Could this be an issue with [invalidating cache](https://medium.com/@martinseanhunt/how-to-invalidate-cached-data-in-apollo-and-handle-updating-paginated-queries-379e4b9e4698)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I think of two ways of resolving it.

1. You could use a state management solution, like redux, flux or context.
2. Or you could pass a function to the deleteComponent to update the parent (or refetch the items)

Regards.

Comment: I think option 2 is my best bet but could you elaborate on this or show some example?

Comment: Hi @VanessaVentura, I'm sorry for not paying attention with your first comment, but i'm glad that you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The question is now updated with functioning code**

In the end, I created a deleteItem function in my parent component of RankList and passed this function down the chain all the way to DeleteButton component and executed it in onConfirm to update the parent state.